# SharePoint 2010: "Failed to create sample data" when running Wizard after installing language pack

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I’m installing a spanish lang pack on SP 2010 and Wizard that runs after installation gives a “failed to create sample data” error, plus this stack:

```
02/11/2011 11:31:59  14  ERR                      Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.EvalProvision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

Searched for this issue, tried couple recipes but no luck. Ideas truly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround is to create a root site collection on port 80. That way, Wizard finishes successfully.

Comment: Facing a similar error with Sharepoint 2013 on Windows Server 2008 R2 where it fails after step 7. You got a chance to upgrade and live through this by any chance?